Proof of Blanchard Kahn conditions
I am trying to understand proof of BK conditions given in the appendix to their paper.
In their paper authors have original model:

There $X_{t + 1} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, P_{t + 1} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ This model is transformed into

by using the fact that $A = C^{-1} \Lambda C$. $\Lambda$ also is the matrix of eigenvalues of A, which are sorted in increasing order by modulus: $|\lambda_{11}| < |\lambda_{22}| < ... < |\lambda_{(m+n)(m+n)}|$.
After constuction of $\Lambda$ we can decompose it into two submatrixes:

There $\Lambda_1$ consist of eigenvalues that are inside unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$. And $\Lambda_2$ consist of eigenvalues that are outside unit circle. By definition $\Lambda_1$ has $\bar{n}$ rows and columns. And $\Lambda_2$ has $\bar{m}$ rows and columns. It folows then that vector $Y_t$ may not have same amount of elements as $X_t$ because

and $B_{11} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times \bar{n}}$. So $Y_t$ has $\bar{n}$ elements. We also know that $n + m = \bar{n} + \bar{m}$.
So there are my question:
Appendix of paper Blanchard Kahn (1980) says that we can divide our original system of equations into two subsystems (yes, we can). Second subsystem will be $E_t[Q_{t+1}] = \Lambda_2 Q_t + (C_{21} \gamma_1 + C_{22} \gamma_2) Z_t$. It is also stated that system will explode unless:
$Q_t = -\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \Lambda_2^{-i-1}(C_{21}\gamma_1 + C{22} \gamma_2)E_t[Z_{t+i}]    \quad(1)$
However it does not seem to be obvious since we obtain (1) by just iterating formula $E_t[Q_{t+1+i}] = \Lambda_2 Q_{t+i} + (C_{21} \gamma_1 + C_{22} \gamma_2) Z_{t + i}$ for $i=0,...,\infty$. So how does non-explosiveness follows from (1)?

Expression (1) only follows from $\mathbb{E}_t[Q_{t+1}]=\Lambda_2Q_t+(C_{21} \gamma_1 +C_{22}\gamma_2)Z_t$ if we make an assumption about how fast $Q_t$ grows relative to $\Lambda_2$.
To see this, notice you can write the expression $\mathbb{E}_t[Q_{t+1}]=\Lambda_2 Q_t +(C_{21}\gamma_1+C_{22}\gamma_2)Z_t$ as $$Q_t=-\Lambda_2^{-1}(C_{21}\gamma_1+C_{22}\gamma_2)Z_t+\Lambda_2^{-1}\mathbb{E}_t[Q_{t+1}]$$
This defines a recurrence relation of the form $Q_t=\Lambda_2^{-1}B_t+\Lambda_2^{-1}\mathbb{E}_t[Q_{t+1}]$ where $B_t=-(C_{21}\gamma_1+C_{22}\gamma_2)Z_t$. Iterating this expression forwards $$\begin{align*} Q_t &= \Lambda_2^{-1}B_t+\Lambda_2^{-1}\mathbb{E}_t[Q_{t+1}] \\
&=\Lambda_2^{-1}B_t +\Lambda_2^{-1}\mathbb{E}_t[\Lambda_2^{-1}B_{t+1}+\Lambda_2^{-1}\mathbb{E}_{t+1}[Q_{t+1}]] \\
&= \Lambda_2^{-1}B_t +\Lambda_2^{-2}\mathbb{E}_t[B_{t+1}]+\Lambda_2^{-2}\underbrace{\mathbb{E}_t[\mathbb{E}_{t+1}[Q_{t+1}]]}_{=\mathbb{E}_t[Q_{t+1}]} \\
&=\Lambda_2^{-1}B_t +\Lambda_2^{-2}\mathbb{E}_t[B_{t+1}]+\Lambda_2^{-2}\mathbb{E}_t[Q_{t+1}] \\
& \ \ \vdots \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\Lambda_2^{-i-1}\mathbb{E}_t[B_{t+i}]+\lim_{\tau\to \infty}\Lambda_2^{-\tau-1}\mathbb{E}_t[Q_{t+\tau}] \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\Lambda_2^{-i-1}\mathbb{E}_t[-(C_{21}\gamma_1+C_{22}\gamma_2)Z_{t+i}]+\lim_{\tau\to \infty}\Lambda_2^{-\tau-1}\mathbb{E}_t[Q_{t+\tau}] \\
&=-\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\Lambda_2^{-i-1}(C_{21}\gamma_1+C_{22}\gamma_2)\mathbb{E}_t[Z_{t+i}]+\lim_{\tau\to \infty}\Lambda_2^{-\tau-1}\mathbb{E}_t[Q_{t+\tau}]
\end{align*}$$
Therefore, non-explosiveness corresponds to $\lim_{\tau\to \infty}\Lambda_2^{-\tau-1}\mathbb{E}_t[Q_{t+\tau}]=0$. As $\Lambda_2$ contains the eigenvalues outside the unit circle, $\Lambda_2^{-\tau-1}$ tends to the 0 matrix. Therefore, this condition is saying that for non-explosive behaviour we need $\mathbb{E}_t[Q_{t+\tau}]$ to grow at a rate slower than $\Lambda_2^{\tau}$. This limit condition is similar to the transversality condition which also precludes explosive paths.

This was really helpful and enlightening. Thank you.
